Given $T$ self-adjoint and $(e_n)_n\subset\mathcal{D}(T)$ basis, if $S$ maps $e_n$ into $\mathcal{D}(T)$, does it map $\mathcal{D}(T)$ into itself?
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space, $T$ a self-adjoint operator on it with domain $\mathcal{D}(T)$, and $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a complete orthonormal set of $\mathcal{H}$ completely contained into $\mathcal{D}(T)$ (not necessarily eigenvectors of $T$). Assume that $S\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ has the following property: for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $Se_n\in\mathcal{D}(T)$.
My question is: is this property sufficient to ensure that $S\mathcal{D}(T)\subset\mathcal{D}(T)$? At first I thought this was true, but I haven't been able to prove it (I tried to use the fact that $T$, being self-adjoint, is closed) so far.

No, this is not true. For example, let $T$ be the diagonal operator on $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ that sends $e_n$ to $(n!)e_n$, $S$ be the unilateral shift, i.e., $Se_n = e_{n+1}$. Then $v = \sum_n \frac{1}{(n+1)!} e_n \in \mathcal{D}(T)$ but $Sv = \sum_n \frac{1}{(n+1)!}e_{n+1} \notin \mathcal{D}(T)$.
